# C# WFA - delegate time consuming work to another thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, delegates, task

I would like to create some mechanism in C# (WFA) that allows me to add some functions to one specific separated Thread on the fly.

```
public class MyClass
{
    private Thread specialThread = new Thread();
    MyClass()
    {
        regularMethod();
        specialThread.AddNextJob( veryLongTimeConsumingMethod() );
        //....
        anotherUseMethod();
    }
    private void veryLongTimeConsumingMethod()
    {
        //...time consuming database, logic, etc...
        this.UIThread(delegate ()
        {
            control1.Items = updatedItems;
        });
    }

    private void anotherUseMethod()
    {
        //...another method wants to do a long job
        specialThread.AddNextJob(veryLongTimeConsumingMethod());
    }
}
```

I want the 'specialThread' to be on "standby" (waiting for another 'job') after all 'jobs' are done. I need to make all 'jobs' in order they were added.
Is there any common way to achive this?

Answer (score -1):

I wrote something like this a while ago. Nowadays you'd probably use async await to get stuff to run on background threads. But here's a quick TaskQueue I wrote.

```
public class TaskQueue
{
    public Queue<Task> CurrentTasks { get; private set; }
    public bool TaskQueueRunning { get; private set; }

    public TaskQueue()
    {
        CurrentTasks = new Queue<Task>();
        TaskQueueRunning = false;
    }

    public void AddTask(Task task)
    {
        CurrentTasks.Enqueue(task);
        ProcessTasks();
    }

    private void ProcessTasks()
    {
        if (!TaskQueueRunning)
        {
            TaskQueueRunning = true;
            ProcessIndividualTask();
        }
    }

    private void ProcessIndividualTask()
    {
        if (CurrentTasks.Count > 0)
        {
            TaskItem currenttask = CurrentTasks.Dequeue();
            currenttask.CurrentTask.ContinueWith(x => ProcessIndividualTask());
            currenttask.CurrentTask.Start();
        }
        else
        {
            TaskQueueRunning = false;
        }
    }
}
```

You instantiate it on your main form with:

```
private TaskQueue backgroundtasks = new TaskQueue();
```

Then when you want to perform a method on a background thread you wrap it in a task. E.G.

```
Task newtask = new Task(() => MyMethodCall());
backgroundtasks.AddTask(newtask);
```

Or if you want to inline the whole thing:

```
backgroundtasks.AddTask(new Task(() => MyMethodCall()));
```

If there are no items on the task queue then the queue will not run, if you add an item the queue will run. If you add multiple items when the first task completes it will `ContinueWith` the next task. Tasks will always be run in the sequence because the underlying type is a queue and it will only run the next task once the current task is complete.

One limitation of this is that your tasks cannot return results. You can set up a task to write to a variable though. E.G.

```
Task newtask = new Task(() => {
                                  myvar = MyMethodCall();
                              });
backgroundtasks.AddTask(newtask);
```

This assumes you have a property/variable on your main form called myvar. But be careful with this because if you write to the same variable multiple times from different tasks you won't be able to predict what the value will be at anyone time - especially if you access it from a different thread. Talking of cross-threading - there's no guarding here so be especially careful.

You would be advised to look into Async and Await as you might find these fit better with what you want to do.

Comment: Would the downvoter care to comment on why this answer was downvoted?